# Split on capital letters and numbers

Tags: perl, cgi, cgi-bin

I need this script to split on capital letters and numbers. I've got the split on capital letters part working but I can't seem to figure out the number side of it.

Needed result: `Hvac System 8000 Series :: Heating System 8000 Series :: Boilers`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;

my $Last_URL = "HvacSystem8000Series/HeatingSystem8000Series/Boilers";


my ($Cat,$Sub1,$Sub2) = split(/\//, $Last_URL, 3);

if ($Sub2) {

    $Last_URL = "<b>$Cat :: $Sub1 :: $Sub2</b>";
}
else {

    $Last_URL = "<b>$Cat :: $Sub1</b>";
}

my @Last_URL = $Last_URL =~ s/(.)([A-Z][^A-Z][^0-9])/$1 $2/g;
print "$Last_URL";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few `s///` transformations will give you what you need:

```
for ($Last_URL) {
    s/ ([a-z]) ([A-Z0-9]) / "$1 $2" /egx;  # Foo123 -> Foo 123
    s/ ([0-9]) ([A-Z]) / "$1 $2" /egx;     # 123Bar -> 123 Bar
    s! / ! " :: " !egx;                    #   /    -> " :: "
}
print $Last_URL, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just use a regular expression match to find all the required "words" within the string and then join them with spaces. This program demonstrates. It counts `/` as a word, so these can just be substituted for double colons to complete the process

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Last_URL = "HvacSystem8000Series/HeatingSystem8000Series/Boilers";

(my $string = join ' ', $Last_URL =~ m<[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+|/>g) =~ s|/|::|g;

print $string;
```

**output**

```
Hvac System 8000 Series :: Heating System 8000 Series :: Boilers
```

Answer (score 0):

Like pilcrow's answer but, you know, different

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "HvacSystem8000Series/HeatingSystem8000Series/Boilers";

$string =~ s/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu}|\pN)/ /g;
$string =~ s/(?<=\pN)(?=\p{Lu})/ /g;
$string =~ s'/' :: 'g;

print "$string\n";
```